# Silverlight toolkit transition stopping half way when the application is reactivated

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, transition

I'm using the nov 11 silverlight toolkit, and I just copy pasted the basic transitions to spice up my app a bit without doing much work. I'm referring to this code:

```
<!--some really simple basic navigation animations to get us started-->
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

This works great, except for when I am reactivating the application after it has been tombstoned. It appears that the transition stops halfway through. The application remains responsive, but looks completely messed up. Like this:

[image: this screenshot]

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I think it might have something to do with my viewmodel and that it gets populated during the transition... So if that's the case, is there an event I can subscribe to for when the transition is done? then I can unsupress the property changed event in my viewmodel. But the transition works perfectly when I'm just navigating around my app, so that probably isn't it.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm using this code http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=74 in multiple apps and haven't seen such a problem...

Comment: That method only allows for one type of animation though right? I currently have many different transition animations in different pages, since it sometimes made more sense to have different ones.

Comment: For some reason doing this does work for me... but it still doesn't make any sense. I would still prefer to have different transitions on each page (they make more sense with the way my app is structured)

Comment: Show me some code behind c# code..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=74

You can define multiple transitions in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="Transition" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
            ...
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Transition2" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
            ...
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Transition3" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
            ...
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**And set the transition for each page:**

In page 1:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ... Style="{StaticResource Transition}">
```

In page 2:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ... Style="{StaticResource Transition2}">
```

In page 3:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ... Style="{StaticResource Transition3}">
```

**Have you tried moving the resource declaration to the page?**

Something like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Name="MyPage">
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LocalTransition">
            ...
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

C# code behind:

```
public class MyPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Style = (Style)Resources["LocalTransition"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot soon and let you know